# connect forms through php and primary key

Tags: php, forms, function, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to connect forms using one of the inputs as a form of primary key.

For example,

---first form where the primary key is taken

```
form1.php
```

---second form, where page1 is based on an input from form1

```
form2.php?page1=primary key
```

---third form, where page1 is based on an input from form2

```
form3.php?page2=primary key
```

---fourth form, where page2 is page1

```
form4.php?page3=primary key
```

---fourth form, where page3 is page2

and so on, until the last page. My question is how do i connect them? how do i retrieve the primary and pass it on all the form involved? So far I can only pass the primary key up to form2, when it reaches form3, it disappears.

By the way, after each form is accomplished, it proceeds to a process page.

---below is the code for a sample form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="eval_2.php">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>
            <td width="70%">
            <strong>1. Quality of Work </strong><br />
            - refers to his/her ability to work with thoroughness.
            </td>
            <td align="center"> <select name="qualityremark">
              <option>Select Remark</option>
              <option>O</option>
              <option>VS</option>
              <option>S</option>
              <option>US</option>
              <option>P</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70%" height="10%"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; a. Works outstandingly accurate and complete in details</td>
            <td width="30%" align="left"> O - Outstanding </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="70%"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; b. Does thorough work; rarely commit errors</td>
            <td width="30%" align="left"> VS - Very Satisfactory </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="70%"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; c. Fairly completes work with few errors</td>
            <td width="30%" align="left"> S - Satisfactory </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="70%"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; d. Work is often incomplete, inaccurate</td>
            <td width="30%" align="left"> US - Unsatisfactory</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="70%"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;e. Very careless work; errors frequently repeated</td>
            <td width="30%" align="left"> P - Poor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> Comments: </td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><textarea name="qualitycomment" cols="80" rows="5" id="qualitycomment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            </table>    
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><div align="right">
            <a href="performanceeval.php">Back</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <!--<a href="performanceeval3.php">Next</a> -->
            <input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" id="next" class="silver_button"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
            </tr><br /> 
            </form>
```

---below is the code for the process page

```
require_once("dbconnect_gentemplate.php");
require_once("attendanceClass.php");

$newAcct= new attendance();
$m=$newAcct->eval_2();

$current=$_GET['page1'];


header("Location: performanceeval3.php?page2=$current");
```

---below is the code for a function

```
function eval_2(){ //page 2

$current=$_GET['page1'];

// $command="select recentact from ojt_evaluation";
// $commando=mysql_query($command) or die("Error ".mysql_error());
// $commander=mysql_fetch_array($commando);

// $current=$commander['recentact'];
// $cur=md5($current);

 if(isset($_POST['next'])){ 
    $qualityremark=$_POST['qualityremark'];
    $qualitycomment=$_POST['qualitycomment'];

    if(trim($qualityremark)=="") return  "<p>Error creating account;blank qualityremark</p>";

    $sql="update ojt_evaluation set qualityremark='$qualityremark', qualitycomment='$qualitycomment' where student='$current'";

    $query=mysql_query($sql)or die ("Error".mysql_error());
    }
    // header("Location: performanceeval3.php?session=$current");
}
```

Where did I go wrong? What should I do? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you didn't pass any query string

in the below variable will be null there is no parameter value assign to page1

```
 $current=$_GET['page1'];
```

and one more think the submit button will click the action of form in loaded

may u try this

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="eval_2.php?page1=form1">
```

Comment: page1 is assigned as 

    `$current=$_POST['student'];
    header("Location: performanceeval2.php?page1=$current");`

    `$_POST['student']` is the input taken from form1 to be used as the 'primary key'

Comment: since it would be too long to post as a comment, i've put it on shrib, --> http://shrib.com/form1_ayou

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating your variable correctly.

```
header("Location: performanceeval3.php?page2=$current");
```

Try this

```
header('Location: performanceeval3.php?page2=' . $current . ');
```